# Inserting not centered image in Latex

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I do not have any problem inserting images on LaTex, but As I have a big image when inserting It with:

```
\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]{image.png}\
```

It appears centered, as it is a little big, I would like to be inserted from the most left side (not in center)

- How do you modify that line to add image in the left and not in the center of document?
- Is it possible to change margin just for this image, then return margins as original place?

I put an example of something like I am getting...And the one I am searching for...

[image]

Comment: Wasn't it required to use either `\centering` or a `center` environment inside the `figure` to get a centered image? So just remove that?

Comment: well, I do not have `\begin{center}` or anything similar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your image to be exactly the width of the text (or `\linewidth` actually), then you should use

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
```

This way the image will always be centered if it was wider than `\linewidth` to start with. If, however, the image has a width *less than* `\linewidth`, then it will always be typeset 'starting on the left' if there is nothing preceding it. It may be, if you do not put the image in a `figure` environment - but in a paragraph rather - that a paragraph indent could cause it to shift over to the right. In that case, use

```
\noindent \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
```

Using a fixed spacing (like `\hspace*{-1.5in}`) to move a figure left (or right, with positive length) may look visually effective, but it not always truly accurate. Hence the suggestion to use *relative* lengths (like `width=\linewidth`) which depend on other parameters set by LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

The standard method for centering an image slightly larger than the line width is to say

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\includegraphics[...]{...}}
```

However, trying to set the image not wider than the line width is better.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do:

```
\hspace*{-1.5in}
\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]{image.png}\\
```